# JUnit Plug-in Test Ignores Target Platform in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

I have some problems getting JUnit plug-in tests to work using Eclipse Neon M7 and I'd really like input from anybody out there who uses tests (there has to be *somebody*, right?).

Whenever I start a test that works in Eclipse Luna (but [didn't in Mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657010/junit-plug-in-tests-ignoring-target-platform), which I assumed was a bug) and continues to work using Tycho I get the following exception:

```
!SESSION 2016-05-11 10:25:41.456 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_73
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -version 3 -port 60297 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames org.acme.test.test.core.ActivatorTest -application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication -testApplication org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -testpluginname test.core
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -version 3 -port 60297 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames org.acme.test.test.core.ActivatorTest -application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication -testApplication org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -data C:\workspaces\MyWorkspace/../junit-workspace -dev file:C:/workspaces/MyWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/pde-junit/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -testpluginname test.core

!ENTRY org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime 4 0 2016-05-11 10:25:42.373
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime [81]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.11.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime 2 0 2016-05-11 10:25:42.719
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime [81]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.11.0,4.0.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-05-11 10:25:42.720
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.acme.test.rxp.rxpdemo, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Clearly it's not a Eclipse bug at this point, but I'm doing something wrong. There is no indication what kind of plug-ins are started in the test, but judging from the version ranges I assume it's the wrong ones again - the plug-ins of the running Eclipse instance instead of the plug-ins defined in the workspace's target platform.

Still the launch configuration claims the later target platform is used.

How do I configure a plug-in unit test so that it will take the currently active target platform?

Comment: Is your target platform based on Eclipse 3.7/8? I have run into a similar problem when my dev and target platform version were different and I will try to dig out what I did to resolve it.

Comment: @JonahGraham Yes, it is Eclipse 3.7 and so notably older than Eclipse Neon. Please dig the solution to the problem out :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem and therefore the solution. I have provided my notes as a an answer in the hope that it helps you a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that Eclipse 4.4 (Luna, 2014) and below had a version of *org.eclipse.core.runtime* that was compatible with the host Eclipse version of *org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime*. That changed with 4.5 when the dependency increased.

As you have correctly concluded that the configuration is pointing at the wrong *org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime*. This is probably due to uncleared configuration state. Ensure that the configuration is being cleared, so you don't run with a stale version. That is ensure that *Clear the configuration area before launching* is checked in the  *Configuration* tab of launch configuration.

You can see exactly what PDE has resolved as the configured bundles by looking at *${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/pde-junit/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info* (location specified in *Configuration* tab of launch configuration)

Comment: Both "Clear Workspace Data" and "Clear the configuration area before launching" is checked on default for the tests, so there is nothing I could change. Why does he even use any other version except for the one in the workspace's target platform? And we don't have the `simpleconfigurator` in our default target platforms - but if that's the problem I'll try and add it.

Comment: The `simpleconfigurator` helped me figure out that my target platform was missing "`org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime`", and so Eclipse used the one in its plug-in folder for some strange reason.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `bundles.info` file where you can see which bundles were resolved by PDE - it helped me solve a similar issue which was caused by `org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime` being loaded from my Eclipse installation instead of the target platform